# data switch has no effect when given in eclipse.ini

Tags: eclipse, scala-ide

I want to set up workspace location for an Eclipse instance in order to distribute it to some of my friend. I must use relative path to workspace for this. So far I decided to use data switch to point particular workspace located inside the Eclipse directory. The problem is when I use command-line switch like this:

```
./eclipse -data workspace
```

it works fine, but when I try to add this at the end of `eclipse.ini` like this

```
-data
workspace
```

it does not seem to have any effect. Note that I've tried to restart Eclipse with `clean` switch after editing `eclipse.ini`.

I noticed that setting `osgi.instance.area` in `eclipse/configuration/config.ini` let me point to workspace but I couldn't get relative (to elcipse directory) path working. I tried a number of solutions (`@user.dir/workspace`, `platform\:/base/workspace` and just `workspace`), all they actually compute relative path from user home directory (and `platform` solution creates directory named `platform` in user's home).

The desired behaviour is implemented in [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/), but I can't figure out how they get this.

Comment: If the `eclipse.ini` contains a `-vmargs` entry then everything in file after that is treated as a vmarg **not** an Eclipse argument. So put the `-data` at the start of the file.

Comment: @greg-449 ah, it works, so please convert your comment to answer. But this again does not allow to use path relative to elipse directory: relative path is computed from user home directory. Guess I'll have to open new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When add to the `eclipse.ini` file check if there is a `-vmargs` entry in the file. Everything in the file after any `-vmargs` is treated as a VM argument not an Eclipse argument.

So add the `-data` at the start of the file.